# Mongo sharding without shutdown the existing mongo instance

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I need to do sharding **without** shutdown or restart the existing mongo instance in the port **27017** .

I tried the following, (while the default port is running and mongo instance)

```
mongod --shardsvr --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/dba --port 10001 > /var/log/mongodb/shardlog/sharda.log &
mongod --shardsvr --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/dbb --port 10002 > /var/log/mongodb/shardlog/shardb.log &

mongod --configsvr --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/config --port 20000 > /var/log/mongodb/shardlog/configdb.log &
mongos --configdb localhost:20000 > /var/log/mongodb/shardlog/mongos.log &
```

Then mongos log giving an error,

> ```
> Thu Aug 23 14:44:36 [mongosMain] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
> Thu Aug 23 14:44:36 [mongosMain] ERROR:   addr already in use
> ```

mongos is running on port 20000 but why It's trying to connect the default **27017** port?

Can I start mongos with several shards without disturbing the existing mongo instance on port 27017 ?

Comment: This would be a good question to be asked in ServerFault

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the the list of commands you have given, it looks like you have not told the `mongos` to start on a different port than default.

You would need to supply the `--port` argument for `mongos` to start on a different port.

Try: `mongos --configdb localhost:20000 --port 10003`

Note: `mongos` is not running on port 20000 as you have said above.  You have the config server running on that port